# 1054 - Unknown column in field list subquery mysql

Tags: mysql, variables, subquery

Help, i trying to get a report day by day, so i try to get this from a table where controls, i was looking about that and i find subquery as table but, when i tried, i get this error. i also find something about deep level of scope in subquerys.

**1054 - Unknown column 'ca.fechaIni_Caja' in 'field list'**

```
SELECT
    d.Servicio_id_Serv AS plan,
        (SELECT COUNT( * ) 
            FROM (
                SELECT ins.id_Ins, DATEDIFF( ins.fechaFin_Ins,  ca.fechaIni_Caja ) AS resto
                FROM Inscripcion ins
                LEFT JOIN Freezing f ON ins.id_Ins = f.Inscripcion_id_Ins
                WHERE ins.estado_Ins =1
                HAVING resto =0
                UNION 
                SELECT ins.id_Ins, DATEDIFF( DATE_ADD( ins.fechaFin_Ins, INTERVAL f.cantidadDias_free
                DAY ) ,  ca.fechaIni_Caja ) AS resto
                FROM Inscripcion ins
                RIGHT JOIN Freezing f ON ins.id_Ins = f.Inscripcion_id_Ins
                WHERE ins.estado_Ins =1
                HAVING resto =0
                ORDER BY resto ASC
            )TablaVencimientos) as contador
    FROM 
    DetalleComprobante d INNER JOIN Cuota c ON d.Cuota_id_Cuo=c.id_Cuo
    INNER JOIN Inscripcion i ON i.id_Ins=c.Inscripcion_id_Ins
    INNER JOIN Comprobante co ON d.Comprobante_id_Comp=co.id_Comp
    INNER JOIN Caja ca ON ca.id_Caja=co.Caja_id_Caja
    WHERE d.Concepto_DComp=1
    GROUP BY ca.fechaIni_Caja,d.Servicio_id_Serv,i.tipo_Ins
    ORDER BY ca.fechaIni_Caja ASC;
```

Comment: First thing I see is the use of table as alias,which is a reserved word.

Comment: So someone is lying to us ;-)

Comment: Also `ca` is not an alias which you named in the second part of the union

Comment: that name i change, 'cause it was "dadadada" and is a variable , not a table